# Cancel async from the outside

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have async series which I use to gather key bindings info from player in my game:

[image: image description]

The whole operation happens as series of calls, one for each key:

```
async.series([
      function(callback){controls.getKey("left", callback);},
      function(callback){controls.getKey("right", callback);},
      ... 
]);
```

While fetching controls, a request is sent to server to create player with given user name. It **may** happen that server denies the request. In that case, event is received and there's no point to continue gathering control keys from the user.

So my question is, does `async.series` return some reference that would allow me to cancel the queue?

I want something like this:

```
var series = async.series([ ... ]); 
game.on("playerRefused", function() {
    series.abort();  // After calling this, the next entry in series fill not execute
});
```

I use separate module for `controls.getKey` and I would not like to refer `game` object in that module. I'm trying to keep my project structured and modular, so the less things depend on each other, the better.

Comment: Why are you getting keybinds for a player who you don't even know can actually play the game? First check if the player can be created, THEN let them configure the keybinds.

Comment: You could have an outside variable set by the abort event. All async calls should check that before executing.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs The whole point of async program model is to increase responsiveness. If player clicks `Create player` and then has to wait .3 seconds for server he'll notice.